# Replace entire field based on another field using gsub in awk

Tags: awk

I have a tab-delimited file called data.txt like this:

```
A       A/A     ATTAA/A      
GT      G/G     GT/GT   
T       T/TATATA   T/T
```

I would like to replace the fields in columns 2-3 with REP if the entire field matches the form column1field/column1field. Like this:

```
A       REP     ATTAA/A      
GT      G/G     REP   
T       T/TATATA   REP
```

So far, I have:

```
awk '{ gsub($1"/"$1,"REP",$0); print $0 }' data.txt
```

This gets close but makes replacements when part of the field matches. Like this:

```
A       REP     ATTAREP      
GT      G/G     REP   
T       REPATATA   REP
```

I want to incorporate ^ and $ but this:

```
awk '{ gsub(/^/$1"/"$1/$/,"REP",$0); print $0 }' data.txt
```

does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I would use a for loop like this:

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){if($i==$1"/"$1){$i="REP"}}}1' file
```

Explanation:

```
{
    # NF holds the number of fields in the record
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
        if($i==$1"/"$1){
            $i="REP"
        }
    }
}

1 # Evaluates to true. awk will print the line
```

Comment: Came up with exactly the same just seconds late, avoided the loop though because of just 2 columns, should be `++`

Answer (score 2):

Am sure this `Awk` could be simplified, in its current form it works,

```
awk -F$'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} { if ($2 == $1"/"$1 || $3 == $1"/"$1) {gsub($1"/"$1,"REP",$2); gsub($1"/"$1,"REP",$3)} }1' data.txt

A REP ATTAREP
GT G/G REP
T REPATATA REP
```

Comment: The `if` checks would be superfluous if the pattern used by gsub would match correctly on field boundaries.

Comment: @hek2mgl: Exactly, deleting this now, after seeing your nice way!

Comment: Well, you can keep it. I would just match on field boundaries

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @Kate : glad that you found it useful. Thanks in stack overflow is by returning a positive vote on the answer. Click on the up arrow near each of the answers you found useful!

Comment: @Inian : `^1` you are welcome, could have done it using var like `s=$1"/"$1; if($2==s || $3==s)gsub(s,"REP",$2); gsub(s,"REP",$3)` had saved some char, may be without scroll bar :)

Comment: @AkshayHegde: Agree I realized it was not the best of the efforts, could be so simply done as you suggested or as the `hek2mgl` answered.